# Can inductors interfere with a BLDC motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, inductor, brushless-dc-motor, interference

I'm working on a student project.  It involves running a [brushless DC motor](https://www.thingap.com/tg515x/) with 70uH external unshielded inductors on each phase.

Can the inductors, seeing as they generate a magnetic field, somehow interfere with the motor or its Hall sensors?
If so, how do I calculate the minimal safe operation distance between the inductors and the motor?

Comment: How far away are the inductors? In air magnetic fields of this kind don't travel far, of approximate order of the size of the inductor.

Comment: Theoretically possible but pretty unlikely. Remember your motor coils generate a much stronger magnetic field, and are much closer to the hall sensors and the permanent magnets can still be detected just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Dannie! The inductors are toroidal, each about 3cm in radius and 2cm apart. Do you think it would be a problem if I placed them 5cm away from the motor?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DKNguyen! The inductors are toroidal, each about 3cm in radius and 2cm apart. Do you think it would be a problem if I placed them 5cm away from the motor?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it even if you had a 200g motor running right beside a 10kg motor.